# TEI critical apparatus, double-end-point attached; How to handle with XSL generating HTML

Tags: xml, xslt, overlapping

i have to process the follwing XML structure:

```
<p>[1] Intencio <emph rend="italic">nostra</emph>
  <anchor xml:id="AJH-L.1.1"/>de<anchor xml:id="AJH-L.1.2"/> some more like this..
</p>
<app from="#AJH-L.1.1" to="#AJH-L.1.2">
  <rdg wit="#V">in</rdg>
</app>
```

into something like:

```
<div>[1] Intencio <span class='italic'>nostra</span>
  de<a href='AJH-L.1.1'>1</a> and so on..
</div>
<div class='appEntry'>
  <span class='rdg'>in</span>
</div>
```

Whereas the 1 is meant to be superscript.

I have no problem building the actual apparat but on building the footnotes, because the Information about the relevant anchors comes from the external apparat-elements.

Aside i have to mention that there can be an additional app-Element from anchor-1 to anchor-4 at the same time.

I have seen a question on how to choose the text between such pseudo-overlapping elements here and it helped me a lot. But i cant find any solutions for this problem.

There must be a solution on such a standard method in TEI but i cant find it and i would be very happy, if anyone would have any suggestions.

Many thanks in advance,
Timo

Comment: You have the beginnings of a good questions but I'm finding it hard to follow. Can you provide the XSL you have tried so far? Also, I don't understand what you mean by "_there can be an additional app-Element from anchor-1 to anchor-4 at the same time_" - can you provide an example?

Comment: @cordsen: Ok, now I know I'm not the only one confused about that :)

Comment: sry for that.I'm actually on a good trail. I am gonna show you my own solution tomorrow or create just more confusion

Answer (score 0):

So here is a more complex example of the XML which includes the overlap problem as well.

```
<div type='subdivision'>
  <p>
    ....
     <anchor xml:id="AJH-L.2.63"/>intellectus cum re que sentitur <anchor
     xml:id="AJH-L.2.64"/>in<anchor xml:id="AJH-L.2.65"/> apprehensione<anchor
     xml:id="AJH-L.2.66"/>
    ....
  </p>
  ....
  <app from="#AJH-L.2.64" to="#AJH-L.2.65">
    <rdg wit="#H #M #N #P #R #V">-</rdg>
  </app>
  <app from="#AJH-L.2.63" to="#AJH-L.2.66">
    <rdg wit="#M">- <emph rend="italic">hom.</emph></rdg>
  </app>
  ....
</div>
```

My XSLT Templates so far:

```
    <xsl:template match="TEI:anchor">
      <xsl:variable select="@xml:id" name="anchorId"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::TEI:p/TEI:app[@to=concat('#',$anchorId)]">
        <a class="rs" name="rs_{count(preceding::TEI:app)+1}"
          href="#app_{count(preceding::TEI:app)+1}">
          <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::TEI:app)+1"/>
        </a>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TEI:app">
    <xsl:variable select="substring(@from,2)" name="from"/>
    <xsl:variable select="substring(@to,2)" name="to"/>
    <table class="appEntry">
      <tr rowspan="{count(TEI:rdg)+1}">
        <td>
          <a name="app_{position()}" href="#rs_{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <!-- the referenced text from between the anchors -->
           <xsl:value-of select="//TEI:div[current()]//text()[preceding::TEI:anchor[@xml:id=$from] and following::TEI:anchor[@xml:id=$to]]"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="TEI:rdg">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <!-- all readings -->
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
```

And the resulting Output should look like the following:

```
<div class="maintext">
  ....
  intellectus cum re que sentitur in <a href="#app_32" name="rs_32" class="rs">32</a>
  apprehensione <a href="#app_33" name="rs_33" class="rs">33</a>
  ....
</div>
<div class="apparatus">
  ....
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#rs_32" name="app_32">32</a><td>
    <td>in</td>
    <td> - </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#rs_33" name="app_33">33</a><td>
    <td>intellectus cum re que sentitur </td>
    <td>- hom.</td>
    </tr>
  ....
</div>
```

Except for the chaotic table this seems to work fine. It wasn't that voodoo as is thought of, once i had made the right start.

I hope, i could specify my question and gave a good answer, too.
What du you think?

greetings,
Timo